# Assign Topic from NNMF Topic Modelling

Tags: python, nlp, nmf

I have a list of text comments that are fed into a non-negative matrix factorization topic modelling program.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# load the data
import csv
with open('C:\\...\\comments.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skip header
    df = [tuple(row) for row in reader]

# set the number of topics 
total_topics = 3

# process the data
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from collections import defaultdict
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import pos_tag
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopwords
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

data_text = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['text'])
# remove stopwords and tokenize the text
custom_stops = ["stopword1", "stopword2", "stopword3"]
data_text['filtered_text'] = data_text['text'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x.lower()))
data_text['filtered_text'] = data_text['filtered_text'].apply(lambda x: str.split(x))
data_text['filtered_text'] = data_text['filtered_text'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item.lower() not in custom_stops])
CORPUS = pd.DataFrame(data_text['filtered_text'])

# Remove empty strings
CORPUS.dropna(inplace=True)
# WordNetLemmatizer requires Pos tags to understand if the word is noun or verb or adjective etc. By default it is set to Noun
tag_map = defaultdict(lambda : wn.NOUN)
tag_map['J'] = wn.ADJ
tag_map['V'] = wn.VERB
tag_map['R'] = wn.ADV
# lemmatize the text
for index,entry in enumerate(CORPUS['filtered_text']):
    # Declaring Empty List to store the words that follow the rules for this step
    Final_words = []
    # Initializing WordNetLemmatizer()
    word_Lemmatized = WordNetLemmatizer()
    # pos_tag function below will provide the 'tag' i.e if the word is Noun(N) or Verb(V) or something else.
    for word, tag in pos_tag(entry):
        # Below condition is to check for Stop words and consider only alphabets
        if word not in stopwords.words('english') and word.isalpha():
            word_Final = word_Lemmatized.lemmatize(word,tag_map[tag[0]])
            Final_words.append(word_Final)
    # The final processed set of words for each iteration will be stored in 'text_final'
    CORPUS.loc[index,'text_final'] = str(Final_words)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer

def build_feature_matrix(documents, feature_type='frequency'):
    feature_type = feature_type.lower().strip()  
    if feature_type == 'binary':
        vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=True, min_df=1,ngram_range=(1, 1))
    elif feature_type == 'frequency':
        vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=False, min_df=1,ngram_range=(1, 1))
    elif feature_type == 'tfidf':
        vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, ngram_range=(1, 1))
    else:
        raise Exception("Wrong feature type entered. Possible values: 'binary', 'frequency', 'tfidf'")
    feature_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents).astype(float)
    return vectorizer, feature_matrix

# create a feature matrix
vectorizer, tfidf_matrix = build_feature_matrix(CORPUS['text_final'], feature_type='tfidf')
td_matrix = tfidf_matrix.transpose()
td_matrix = td_matrix.multiply(td_matrix > 0)

from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
nmf = NMF(n_components=total_topics, random_state=42, alpha=.1, l1_ratio=.5)
nmf.fit(tfidf_matrix) 

def get_topics_terms_weights(weights, feature_names):
    feature_names = np.array(feature_names)
    sorted_indices = np.array([list(row[::-1]) 
                           for row 
                           in np.argsort(np.abs(weights))])
    sorted_weights = np.array([list(wt[index]) 
                               for wt, index 
                               in zip(weights,sorted_indices)])
    sorted_terms = np.array([list(feature_names[row]) 
                             for row 
                             in sorted_indices])
    
    topics = [np.vstack((terms.T, 
                     term_weights.T)).T 
              for terms, term_weights 
              in zip(sorted_terms, sorted_weights)]     
    return topics

def print_topics_udf(topics, total_topics=1,
                     weight_threshold=0.0001,
                     display_weights=False,
                     num_terms=None):
    
    for index in range(total_topics):
        topic = topics[index]
        topic = [(term, float(wt))
                 for term, wt in topic]
        topic = [(word, round(wt,2)) 
                 for word, wt in topic 
                 if abs(wt) >= weight_threshold]
                     
        if display_weights:
            print( 'Topic #' +str(index+1)+' with weights')
            print (topic[:num_terms] if num_terms else topic)
        else:
            print ('Topic #'+str(index+1)+' without weights')
            tw = [term for term, wt in topic]
            print (tw[:num_terms] if num_terms else tw)
        print()

feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
weights = nmf.components_

topics = get_topics_terms_weights(weights, feature_names)
# print topics and weights
# print_topics_udf(topics=topics,total_topics=total_topics,num_terms=None,display_weights=False) 
# print topics with weights
# print_topics_udf(topics=topics,total_topics=total_topics,num_terms=None,display_weights=True) 

# display the topics
# this takes the top term from each group and assigns it as the topic theme
for index in range(0,total_topics):
        print("Topic",index+1,"=",topics[index][0][0])
```

The example output may be something like:

```
Topic 1 = problem
Topic 2 = software
Topic 3 = recommendation
```

How can I assign a specific comment from the file a specific topic? e.g., the comment "My computer has an issue of turning off intermittently" would be mapped to Topic 1 "problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to transform the document term matrix to pull out the factorized document topic matrix:

```
W = nmf.fit_transform(tfidf_matrix)
```

where the tfidf matrix = W x H, where W is the document-topic matrix and H is the topic-term matrix. Slide 25 of the link gives a good visualization of this technique:
http://derekgreene.com/slides/topic-modelling-with-scikitlearn.pdf

Thus, the highest value in W for the respective comment row correlates the assigned topic. I iterated across the rows to assign this topics via

```
data_text['topic'] = ""
for row in range(len(data_text['text'])):
    data_text['topic'][row] = topics[np.argmax(W[row])][0][0]
```

To extend the example in the question, if the `[1]` index row value of `data_text['text'][1]` is "My computer has an issue of turning off intermittently" the `W[1][0][0]` matrix array may be `[0.5412, 0.0201, 0.0]`. Since the highest value is in the first column, this sentence should be mapped to the first topic (i.e., 'problem' topic). The text assignment of this topic is assigned to `data_text['topic'][1]` value via `topics[np.argmax(W[row])][0][0]`